# Too many markers Google Maps

Tags: android, dictionary, google-maps-markers

We added about 200 new markers in the MapView.
Now the app stucks and you cant use the MapView.
I heared about MarkerClusterer but did not found any more inforamation how to use MarkerClusterer with Android...or are there better solutions?

Can anyone give me a link or write a little turorial?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this example Android project https://github.com/igorab/ManyPinsProject

It shows limited amount of markers depending on `MapView` zoom level.

Here is tutorial from Google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers

As @CommonsWare said it is only for JavaScript version or GoogleMaps, but may be you can find something useful there. For example, they have a link to `MarkerClusterer` js source code. Maybe you can find a way to adopt it to Android.

Comment: The tutorial is for the JavaScript version of Google Maps, not the Maps SDK add-on for Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know :( But is there a turorial for Android?

Comment: Not that I am aware of -- I was merely pointing it out so that readers of your answer didn't get confused.

Comment: Updated answer. That github project does the work. There is tutorial explaining how it's done, but only in Russian http://habrahabr.ru/post/139929/

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library – [Android MapView Balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons). This project provides an easy way to annotate map overlay items with a simple information balloon when using the Android Maps.